# Prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is a path-connected topological space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness

I am trying to comprehend how path-connectedness of a topological space is proved in essence to solve another problem (to prove the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ without a line is not path-connected) and have troubles with it.

There is a quite intuitive definition of path-connectedness: a topological space is path-connected if for any two points in that space there exists a continuous function from a compact $[a,b]$ to that space such that its $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are equal to those points respectively.

Now, I've made this simple problem (stated in the title) for myself to understand how it's proved.

The way I think (although it's a hand-waving proof, I do not understand the flaw I've made):

Let's split a closet interval $[0,1]$ into semi-intervals like $(x_1,x_2]$ with $x_2 > x_1$ (and keep the first one starting from 0 to be a closed interval for the sake of symmetry, i.e. the first one is $[0,x]$). Obviously, I can split this interval into countable amount of such semi-intervals. Therefore, since between any two rational points $a$ and $b$ there're countable amount of rationals, I can construct a function mapping these semi-intervals to points in $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ (e.g. I can identify each semi-interval with a rational point enclosed in between to get an enumeration and that match each semi-interval to each point in enumerated set of points in $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ with some bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$). A function constructed as such is continuous because for any rational point in $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ there exists a whole neighbourhood mapped to this single point.
And since we can construct such a continuous function for any two rational points, Q is path-connected.

Thank you!

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not path connected at all. How can you build a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=2$? By the mean value theorem $\sqrt{2}$ would have to be in the image.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why $\sqrt{2}$ should be in the image since the function maps to $\mathbb{Q}$, not to $\mathbb{R}$. Could you explain where I made a mistake? Thank you!

Comment: @Mark Should be intermediate value theorem instead of mean value theorem.

Comment: A function to $\mathbb{Q}$ is a function to $\mathbb{R}$. Actually, it can be proved that the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals.

Comment: @edm Yes, I confuse between these names all the time.

Comment: I think you should take a closer look at your argument. "I can construct a function mapping..."  --- write it down. "... there exists a whole neighborhood mapped to this point" --- what's that neighborhood? In particular are the endpoints of the semi-intervals contained in these neighborhoods?

Comment: @Neal, Oooh, of course! If a semi-interval $(x_1,x_2]$ is mapped to some rational $n_1$, and then the next semi-interval $(x_2,x_3]$ to "the next" rational point $n_2$, then $x_2$ is a point of discontinuity! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mark, thank you after all! Apparently, I did not even understand the true statement of the intermediate value theorem! Although, this and the initial problem appear obvious if I try to use this theorem, the real understanding came to me after I tried to prove these problems using the method used in the prove of the intermediate value theorem itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$, then every continuous map from $I$ into $\mathbb Q$ is constant. In fact, not only $\mathbb Q$ is disconnected, as it is totally disconnected (that is, the only non-empty connected subsets of $\mathbb Q$ are the singletons).

Comment: Well, I do not understand that any map from interval to $\mathbb{Q}$ is constant. Though it seems like a simple analysis problem. Going to prove it and then my flaw is obvious. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to use the existence of irrational numbers to give a separation of $\mathbb{Q}$ in its own subspace topology. For instance,
$$
\mathbb{Q} = (\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\infty, \pi)) \cup (\mathbb{Q} \cap (\pi, +\infty))
$$
exhibits $\mathbb{Q}$ as a disjoint union of two non-empty relative open sets.  Hence $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected, so it cannot be path connected.

Comment: Yes, I understand, to me it even seems quite obvious from the definition of connectedness. However, I had problems exactly with the notion of path-connectedness. As it's appeared, I just did not understand the simplest property of continuous functions :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple curve $\lambda : J \to \mathbb{Q}$, where J is some interval by considering cardinality.  "Simple" meaning $\lambda$ is injective.  And by compactness, any curve connecting two points yields a simple curve connecting the points.  So, we would have a bijection between $J$ (uncountable) and a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (countable), a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right, and if it is, it is only because you are in the Euclidean topology.  There are plenty of topological spaces with a countable number of points that are still path connected.

Comment: Randall I have the feeling you are right.

Comment: If this is true for subspaces of the Euclidean line, it would be nice to see it worked out.  Although then I think it just reduces to the Intermediate Value Theorem approach posted above.

Comment: My argument relies on compactness. (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214526/countable-path-connected-hausdorff-space) Every compact Hausdorff space of size less than the continuum is totally disconnected.

Comment: Interesting.....

Comment: I agree!  For a second there I thought I was in big trouble in Topology land